# Flask Cors isn't working

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, cors, flask-cors

I'm trying to enable CORS in my Flask app, but it seems I can always access my urls from the browser whatever I put in the origins.

I don't know what I do wrong. Here's my code

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app, resources={r'/*': {'origins': 'www.examplesite.com'}})

@app.route('/reports', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index(id=None):
    return jsonify(success=True), 200
```

Comment: You mean you are trying to access it from a url other than www.examplesite.com?

Comment: Yup, and it works. it seems that my CORS configuration has no effect

Comment: Can you tell exactly what are you doing? What is the endpoint you are accessing and from which domain and how?

Comment: I'm trying to access an API only from specific domain to add some security. But doesn't seem to work. And I can access it locally with no problem. I deployed it then tried again from my browser and it also worked. it seems the CORS restore to '*' which is the default.

Answer (score 0):

You have two issues:

1. The key provided to resources must be a valid Python regular expression, according to [Flask-CORS documentation](http://flask-cors.corydolphin.com/en/latest/api.html#extension) - use `/.*` instead of `/*` to match anything under the root `/`, rather than any path which consists only of slashes (which is what `/*` means).
2. The origin returned should be a fully-qualified URI matching the syntax described in [RFC 6454 Section 7.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-7.1), as per [the W3C's specification for CORS](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header).  `www.example.com` is not a fully-qualified URI as it does not have a scheme.  Use `https://www.example.com` or `http://www.example.com` instead.  Alternatively you can use a regular expression to tell Flask-CORS to match both with only one entry in `origins`.

Comment: I did what you told me, still has no effect. It's like the app doesn't see the CORS at all and go with the default.

Comment: Same problem here